# Issue with overflowing div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem which I don't know how to resolve and I hope that some clever people here will have an answer. I've got a "contact form" which is controlled by a jquery slide effect and only appears when a user hovers over an icon. The effect makes the form slide in and out of a right-hand border of a browser, for the whole width of the div containing the form. By default the form is hidden. Up until now I had that div fixed and everything was working fine, but I then realized that it follows the page as I scroll-down, which I don't want. I then made the div absolute, which keeps it in the place, but because I'm hiding the div with a right margin of -250, it pushes the page to the right for that much, adding a scroll bar at the bottom in the process.

Any ideas on how to keep the div from sliding down, but at the same time stop if from overflowing to the right? I think I might need another script which would stop a fixed div from sliding down, but this is just an idea. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it would be much more helpful if you included parts of your code.

Comment: Put it in fiddle if possible

Comment: Why not just add `overflow: hidden` to your `body` tag?

Comment: Post some code or a demo. It's not reasonable to ask people to troubleshoot thin air.

Comment: Cheers guys, I've just added the Fiddle below.

Answer (score 0):

Give the form a right:0; 
this will always keep the form aligned to the right edge and without overflowing..

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="trigger">Show Form</div>
   <div id="form">
        Form Contents go here
   </div>
```

```
#container{
   position: relative;
}
#form{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  width: 250px; 
  height: 100px; /* for demo */
  background: #999; /* for demo */
}
#form.visible{
   display: block;
}

$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#trigger").click(function() {
     $("#form").addClass("visible");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/medmu/2/

Comment: Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zarko/46MEJ/. If you hover over the transparent element on the right, you'll see the contact form appear. However, as you scroll down to "Section 2", the contact form will slide down, which I don't want. I want it to be confined within it's parent element, which is "header". Thanks.

Comment: Thanks user20140268, I added overflow-x to the body and that sorted the issue! So simple yet it totally didn't occur to me. Issue resolved now.